# Using ostream_iterator on vector of pointers

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
std::vector<int*> osd;
osd.push_back(new int(2));
osd.push_back(new int(3));

std::ostream_iterator<int*, char> out_iter2(std::cout, " " );
copy(osd.begin(),osd.end(), out_iter2);
```

output: 0x8e6388 0x8e6a8

How do I make the iterator to print the actual values? Do I need to specialize it?

I made a specialized operator for it but it still doesn't work

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int*>::iterator pd)
{
     return os << *pd << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what `ostream_iterator` is supposed to do - it uses `operator<<`. Why are you using a `vector<int*>` instead of `vector<int>`?

Comment: The ostream_iterator calls something like os<<*iter (not os<<iter) internally, so specialize xxxxx::iterator is not useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a lambda expression, which gets the actual value from the pointer, such as:

```
std::ostream_iterator<int, char> out_iter2(std::cout, " " );
std::transform(osd.begin(), 
               osd.end(), 
               out_iter2, 
               [] (int* x) { return *x; }
              );
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/f85IEk)

**EDIT**

Here's a possible implementation image from the above link:

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt, class UnaryOperation>
OutputIt transform(InputIt first1, InputIt last1, OutputIt d_first, 
                   UnaryOperation unary_op)
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        *d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++);
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Comment: Question: when was "transform" actually called?

Comment: @CarloBrew When you need to do some conversion on the element, while `std::copy` just copy elements to the dest, without any change on them.

Comment: Hmm i am still confused when was the function actually "triggered" from your code. Is it called during the declaration of `transform` ?

Comment: @CarloBrew You mean the 2nd line (`std::transform...`)? It's a function call, not a declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79600/discussion-between-carlo-brew-and-songyuanyao).